# How do I reload page on click of Vuetify Button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vuetify.js

I need to refresh the current page when a user clicks the refresh button.  I'm using Vuetify to generate the button.

```
<v-btn fab dark>
     <v-icon dark>refresh</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

I know in place of the router I can specify `<v-btn fab dark to="myDesiredPath"` but I need to refresh whatever route the user is currently on.

I know in vanilla js I can use location.reload(), but I don't know how to feed that to the button on the user's click.

Comment: Update: I used `<v-button fab dark onclick="location.reload(true)>` which works but it causes a problem with some routes not rendering with their props

Answer (score 18):

you can just create a method in Vue that runs the vanilla JS and then run that method `@click` of the v-btn.

```
methods: {
  reloadPage(){
    window.location.reload()
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but it causes a problem with some routes not rendering with their props. The page needs to reload on the route, but it also needs to keep the properties passed by the route

Comment: method is not necesssaary